# Sqlite Syntax Error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, syntax

I get this error:

```
06-30 12:26:28.987: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14818): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "when": syntax error: CREATE TABLE hTable (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, who TEXT, message TEXT, when TEXT)
```

Really confused to be host. Sat staring at it for about 15 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHEN` is a reserved keyword.  You'll need to change the column name or escape it.

See: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html